# Clipping multipart polygons iteratively

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, buffer, clip, overlapping-features

I have a shapefile of buffers (n=10) and a shapefile of watersheds (n=10). Both shapefile contain overlapping features. I would like to clip each watershed feature with it's corresponding buffer, based on a common ID field (highlighted area below). I'm thinking ModelBuilder should be able to do this, but haven't been able to figure it out. I also have each watershed as an individual file if that helps.

[image: watershed and buffer clip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model illustrated below worked in a test I ran just now.

When you configure the parameters for the two **Select** tools use something like **"ID" = %Value%** as the **Expression**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I found this solution easier to use, but both worked.

Answer (score 2):

Does your watershed layer contain a field that is the ID of the point that was used to generate the watershed and your circular buffers?

If so you could create a model that uses a feature iterator to select the buffer, select the watershed and then run the clip tool. The clip tool will like all geo-processing tools honor any existing selection.

The model you seek is below, you just need to build it and make sure you are using inline variable substitution. If you do not know what they are then read the Help!

[image: Model for clipping watershed]

Comment: +1 Uses one less tool element than my model but looks like it should produce the same result.

Comment: :) We must have been working on a response at the same time! My approach is reliant on the fact that the point that was used to create the buffer is also the point that created the watershed and the ID has been kept by the datasets.